# How to find the name of a HKLM subfolder using Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, after-effects

I wish to install an After Effects plugin on the end-users' system. To ascertain the location of installation, I must find out which version, or versions of After Effects are installed. Because the folder structure looks like this:

```
HKLM/SOFTWARE/Adobe/After Effects/(version)/key
```

It's not very simple. Most graphic designers install more than one version of After Effects. And I must present them with all of them in order to let them choose which version they with to install the plugin on.

Conversely, I wish to present the user with three options:

1. A key that contains the **common** install path
2. A key that contains the **main** install path
3. A **custom** path

How's that going to be possible given the abilities and limitations of Inno Setup?

Thanks.

Comment: Inno has considerable registry support. Have you looked at them at all, especially the `RegGet*` functions?

Comment: It seems to me that what you question title says is something very different then what your question text says. Can you tell us exactly what do you want?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to come up with a custom page for the installer and populate a list box of available choices from the keys you have extracted from the registry. Then based on the one the user selects work accordingly.

I have had similar requirements for AutoCAD but at the time I was provided a standalone executable that I invoked and it displays the various workspaces for me to choose to install to. Then Inno carried on.

So you could write your own little tool that gets fired from the installer and the installer waits. Or do the custom page.

Comment: @MajorDespard As you have accepted an answer that basically does not answer your question, would you please edit your question to ask for the answer you have accepted? (= *"How do I find the installation path of the latest version of After Effects plugin"*?) -- Otherwise your question is useless to other visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know which version is installed on the end user's PC.

It's a piece of cake. :-)

Look at "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.aep": It will rewrite every time the installation is executed. So you know the latest version.

For example, it is 4.0 version when the value of "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.aep" is "aftereffects.project.40". And then you can check out "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AfterEffects.Project.40\shell\open\command". There is the installation path.

That's it.